# Post-Backup Hyper-V Snapshots (StorageCraft ShadowProtect)

Tags: backup, hyper-v

I'm hoping someone with some experience with Hyper-V backups can help me.

We are using Storagecraft ShadowProtect to backup a server with 2 Hyper-V VMs. We do daily incrementals and weekly full backups.

The problem I'm having is that each backup seems to create a snapshot within Hyper-V for each VM, and each time that happens, the usual new differential disk image is created in Hyper-V. Long story short, after a week or two, we find that the disk on the hypervisor is full, and we need to power off the VMs to consolidate these snapshots into the main disk image. We are working around this by simply powering off the VMs for a couple of hours and allowing the consolidation, but we'd ideally like to find a way for this not to be required.

Can anyone shed some light on this process for me? Is having to shut down the VMs regularly to ensure the consolidation happens par-for-the-course with HyperV? Or is something going on that I'm not aware of? I have also tested using the built in Windows Backup and the same thing happens.

Any help would be appreciated. Muchos gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Switch to product using either own CBT (Changed Block Tracking) or one working seamlessly with a "smart" storage + hardware VSS instead of a hypervisor software-level VM-level snapshots. Think of Veeam.